# org.hibernate.query.criteria.internal.BasicPathUsageException: Cannot join to attribute of basic type

Tags: mysql, criteria, criteria-api

I have a problem with criteria query.

In MySQL database a have column person and it is joined with the column passport.
With the help of criteria api I'm trying to get the object/entity Person by the attribute "country" of the object/entity Passport.

The example of code I'm using:

```
public List<Guest> getByPassportCountry(String country) {
    try {
        CriteriaBuilder criteriaBuilder = entityManager.getCriteriaBuilder();
        CriteriaQuery<Guest> query = criteriaBuilder.createQuery(Guest.class);
        Root<Guest> root = query.from(Guest.class);
        Join<Guest, Passport> join = root.join(Guest_.PASSPORT).join(Passport_.COUNTRY);
        query.select(root).where(criteriaBuilder.equal(join.get(Passport_.COUNTRY), country));
        TypedQuery<Guest> result = entityManager.createQuery(query);
        return result.getResultList();
    } catch (NoResultException e) {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Also, there is a connection between these entities:
entity Passport

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "passport_table")
public class Passport extends AEntity{

    @Column(name = "passport_serial")
    private String passportSerial;

    @Column(name = "passport_number")
    private Integer passportNumber;

    @Column(name = "date_of_issue")
    @Convert(converter = StringToDataSQLConverter.class)
    private String dateOfIssue;

    @Column(name = "date_of_expiry")
    @Convert(converter = StringToDataSQLConverter.class)
    private String dateOfExpiry;

    @Column(name = "country")
    private String country;

    //One guest to one passport
    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "guest_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
    private Guest guest;
```

& entity Guest

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "guest_table")
public class Guest extends AEntity {

    @Column(name = "guest_first_name", length = 45)
    private String guestFirstName;

    @Column(name = "guest_last_name", length = 45)
    private String guestLastName;

    @Column(name = "guest_birthdate")
    @Convert(converter = StringToDataSQLConverter.class)
    private String guestBirthDate;

    //Many guests to one room
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "room_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
    private Room room;

    //One passport to one guest
    @OneToOne(mappedBy = "guest")
    private Passport passport;
```

What i've done wrong???
Help please!!!

Answer (score 0):

I've made it

```
public List<Guest> getByPassportCountry(String country) {
        try {
            CriteriaBuilder criteriaBuilder = entityManager.getCriteriaBuilder();
            CriteriaQuery<Guest> query = criteriaBuilder.createQuery(Guest.class);
            Root<Guest> root = query.from(Guest.class);
            Join<Guest, Passport> passport = root.join(Guest_.passport);
            query.select(root).where(criteriaBuilder.equal(passport.get(Passport_.COUNTRY),country));
            TypedQuery<Guest> result = entityManager.createQuery(query);
            return result.getResultList();
        } catch (NoResultException e) {
            return null;
        }
    }
```